# ioctl returns 22 - invalid argument when compiled with clang compiler for FreeBSD

Tags: c, clang, freebsd

Problem : I have an issue with a sample program to get the ip address which is working fine when I am compiling it with FreeBSD built in gcc. But when I am using cross compiler clang version 3.7.1 , I am getting invalid argument error in ioctl call. 
Here is the sample program --

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h> /* for strncpy */

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <errno.h>

int
main()
{
 int fd;
 struct ifreq ifr;

 fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

 /* I want to get an IPv4 IP address */
 ifr.ifr_addr.sa_family = AF_INET;

 /* I want IP address attached to "eth0"/em0 */
 strncpy(ifr.ifr_name, "em0", IFNAMSIZ-1);

 ioctl(fd, SIOCGIFADDR, &ifr);
printf("\n ioctl retrun : %d",errno);

 close(fd);

 /* display result */
 printf("\n%s\n", inet_ntoa(((struct sockaddr_in *)&ifr.ifr_addr)->sin_addr));

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: You must never test the value of `errno` unless the preceding library function produced an error return (-1 in the case of `ioctl`) and is documented as setting `errno` on error (which `ioctl` does). Library functions do not set `errno` to 0, so a non-zero value of `errno` could be left over from a previous call.

Comment: Also, `strncpy` is not solving any problem for you in that call. You might as well use `strcpy`. However, that's not your problem. You say that you are using clang as a "cross-compiler". What is the host OS and what is the platform you run the compiled code on? (Indeed, I have the same doubt about your use of GCC. It should make no difference what compiler you used to build FreeBSD, but perhaps that is not what you meant.) The problem probably has to do with the precise header files you are using...

Comment: In particular, if you are using header files for platform A and running the compiled code on platform B, then it is likely that calls to `ioctl` will fail because the different systems have radically different IOCTL selector numbers. Those numbers are defined as macros in system header files, so it is important that you use the correct headers for the platform you will run the program on.